# Calculating contour for which a point lies / Two-dimensional p-value

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, p-value, spatial, kernel-smoothing

Suppose I have bivariate data $(X_i, Y_i)$ for $i = 1, 2, \dots, I$. I have the following non-parametric method in determining $H_0: \mu_X = \mu_Y = 0$.

1) Compute a 2D KDE on $(X_i, Y_i)$.

2) Calculate the contour for which the point $(0, 0)$ lies.

Here is sample R code:

```
require(ks)
require(mvtnorm)
x = mvrnorm(1000, mu = c(-0.1, 0.1), Sigma = matrix(c(1, -0.2, -0.2, 0.9), nrow = 2))
H.scv <- Hscv(x=x)
f <- kde(x=x, H=H.scv)
plot(f, cont=c(90, 95, 99), xlim = c(-3, 3), ylim = c(-3, 3))
points(0, 0, col = "red")
```

[image]

Of course, I can manually adjust my contour lines and zoom in until I have get lines which intersect with $(0, 0)$, and my $p$-value would then be $1 - $contour.

**Questions**:

1) Is this method of p-value determination valid?

2) How do I programatically determine the contour for which my point lies, and hence determine the $p$-value?

Comment: Your procedure is indeterminate (how exactly do you determine the KDE?), computationally unstable, not based on theory, and potentially produces negative values (because density contours are not probabilities).  Apart from those problems, it could be valid.

Comment: @TomChen, Your matrix Sigma isn't symmetrical. Is it possible?

Comment: @whuber Well, the only thing we need for fitting the KDE is the bandwidth matrix, which can be computed based off cross-validation techniques. The Hscv command in R does exactly that. I agree that the method is computational unstable, especially in the tails, where KDE's don't fit as well. But, negative values are not possible, since the kernels themselves are always positive, unless there is something numerically unstable with contour fitting itself, but it's just simply the highest probability regions?

Comment: @Nick matrix(c(1, -0.2, -0.2, 0.9), nrow = 2) is a symmetric?

Comment: @TomChen, sorry, i mean is it possible that the element Sigma[2,2] is not equal to 1?

Comment: @Nick Sure, Sigma[2, 2] can be any valid symmetric positive-definite matrix. In fact, this example is still using the normal distribution. In general, I'm concerned with sampling from unknown bivariate distributions.

Comment: Negative values are *very* possible: KDE is a *density*, not a probability, which means it can attain arbitrarily large values.  When you subtract them from $1$, as you propose ("1-contour"), you will obtain negative values.  That alone indicates severe problems with this approach.